# unique combination of 2 columns in phpmyadmin database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 3 columns : id, person and code.

I want that the **combination** of `person` and `code` to be *unique* in the table, wich means that the same person with the same code is not allowed more than one time in the table.

How can I set such thing in phpmyadmin?

Thanks for help and excuse my english.

**EDIT**

I have the 2 columns selected in my screen :

[image]

How do i proceed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since id is already primary key, you should choose "unique"
Shown on screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click in table name so to have the fields view.

Select the two fields you need.

Click on key at the bottom of fields.

Comment: I don't think i understand wich 'key' you are talking about. i have uploaded a picture of my screen pls take a look at it and thnx

Comment: @firas The one with "primary" beside

Answer (score 1):

You should select both fields and choose unique key.you can find this key at bottom field near primary key.